# How to hide an untranslated page from language chooser in django cms?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

I want to hide an untranslated page from the language chooser in django cms so that the language chooser shows only the languages that have translations for that page. How can I do that?

One idea is to extend the language chooser template and check there if the language has a translated page but I couldn't find out how to do that.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in django cms 3.0:

```
{% if page and language in page.languages %}
```

for 2.4:

you probably will a custom filter or templatetag that runs::

```
if page.title_set.filter(language=lang).count():
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a beautiful solution, first posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms/z1rdf4C-ltQ

`current_page.get_languages` is the solution. Works with djangocms 3 in my Aldryn project.

`includes/menu/langnav.html`:

```
{% load i18n menu_tags %}
{% if languages|length > 1 %}

{% comment %}
    This is awesome: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms/z1rdf4C-ltQ
{% endcomment %}

<li class="lang">
    {% for language in current_page.get_languages %}
        <a class="{{ language }}{% ifequal current_language language %} selected{% endifequal %}"
           href="{% page_language_url language %}">{{ language }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
{% endif %}
```